# How to delete records in one table based on the values in another table

Tags: sql, oracle

I need to delete the same row in table1 based on the value in table2.

I tried this:

```
DELETE FROM project.wish_list
  USING project.wish_list
  INNER JOIN project.book ON project.wish_list.quantity = project.book.quantity
  WHERE (project.wish_list.quantity = 0);
```

If `quantity = 0` in table `book`, the query should delete the row (with equal isbn) in `wish_list`.

`wish_list` and `book` are similar tables.

Is it possible?

Or an UPDATE of the quantity to -1 for all isbn in the `wish_list` where the `quantity` in the `book` table is 0?

EDIT: delete duplicated with ISBN equal

```
ISBN        title
-------------------
123        Apples      <----- delete
123        Apples      <----- delete
123        Apples      <----- One only has to remain
1234       Pineapple   <-----  NO DELETE
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not quite clear about the question.  Sounds like: remove all `wish_list` entries for books that have quantity 0 in the `book` table?

```
DELETE FROM wish_list
  WHERE isbn IN ( SELECT isbn
                    FROM book
                    WHERE quantity = 0 );
```

Or the update:

```
UPDATE wish_list
  SET quantity = -1
  WHERE isbn IN ( SELECT isbn
                    FROM book
                    WHERE quantity = 0 );
```

Update:  Deleting duplicates from `wish_list` (regardless of quantity).  Please test, I haven't:

```
DELETE FROM wish_list
  WHERE ROWID NOT IN (SELECT MIN(ROWID) FROM wish_list GROUP BY isbn);
```

Comment: thank you. work. and if i want update the quantity -1 in wish list, for each ISBN in cart table? thank you again

Comment: thank you so much. last question: for delete duplicate in a table with ISBN equal? thanks

Comment: isbn equale but except one of course. thanks 

i tried "DELETE FROM wish_list WHERE ISBN = ISBN "; 

but delete ALL

Comment: Which duplicate do you wish to delete: duplicate within `wish_list`, within `book`, any `wish_list` book which has a matching `isbn` in `book` with a quantity > 0?  Can you provide an example of what you expect to happen?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, i replied to the wrong question.